# Multiplying matrices using OpenMP taking much more time than serialized way

Tags: c, matrix, parallel-processing, openmp

When I try to multiply two big square matrices using OpenMP, the parallel way takes much more time than serialized one. Am I doing anything wrong?

A simple test on a machine with 4 cores (hyperthreading on) results in about 100 second for the parallel computation and 10 second for the serial one!

This is my parallel code:

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MATSIZE 500
#define MAXRAND 100

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    double startTime = 0.0, stopTime = 0.0;
    startTime = omp_get_wtime();

    int i, j, k;
    static int  a[MATSIZE][MATSIZE],b[MATSIZE][MATSIZE],c[MATSIZE][MATSIZE];

    srand(time(NULL));

    #pragma omp parallel shared(a,b,c) private(i,j,k)
    {
        #pragma omp for
        for (i=0; i<MATSIZE; i++)
            for (j=0; j<MATSIZE; j++){
                a[i][j]= rand()%MAXRAND;
                b[i][j]= rand()%MAXRAND;
                c[i][j]= 0;
            }
    }

    printf("Matrix A:\n");
    for (i=0; i<MATSIZE; i++){
        for (j=0; j<MATSIZE; j++) 
            printf("%d   ", a[i][j]);
        printf("\n"); 
    }
    printf("******************************************************\n");
    printf("Matrix B:\n");
    for (i=0; i<MATSIZE; i++){
        for (j=0; j<MATSIZE; j++) 
            printf("%d   ", b   [i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("******************************************************\n");

    #pragma omp parallel shared(a,b,c) private(i,j,k)
    {   
        #pragma omp for
        for (i=0; i<MATSIZE; i++){
            for(j=0; j<MATSIZE; j++)       
                for (k=0; k<MATSIZE; k++){
                    c[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
                    printf(".");
                }
        }
    }

    printf("\nResult Matrix:\n");
    for (i=0; i<MATSIZE; i++){
        for (j=0; j<MATSIZE; j++) 
            printf("%d   ", c[i][j]);
        printf("\n"); 
    }
    stopTime = omp_get_wtime();
    printf("Elapsed time = %f \n", stopTime - startTime);
}
```

And here is the serial one:

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MATSIZE 500
#define MAXRAND 100

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    double startTime = 0.0, stopTime = 0.0;
    startTime = omp_get_wtime();

    int i, j, k;
    static int  a[MATSIZE][MATSIZE],b[MATSIZE][MATSIZE],c[MATSIZE][MATSIZE];

    srand(time(NULL));

    for (i=0; i<MATSIZE; i++)
        for (j=0; j<MATSIZE; j++){
            a[i][j]= rand()%MAXRAND;
            b[i][j]= rand()%MAXRAND;
            c[i][j]= 0;
        }

    printf("Matrix A:\n");
    for (i=0; i<MATSIZE; i++){
        for (j=0; j<MATSIZE; j++) 
            printf("%d   ", a[i][j]);
        printf("\n"); 
    }
    printf("******************************************************\n");
    printf("Matrix B:\n");
    for (i=0; i<MATSIZE; i++){
        for (j=0; j<MATSIZE; j++) 
            printf("%d   ", b   [i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("******************************************************\n");

    for (i=0; i<MATSIZE; i++){
        for(j=0; j<MATSIZE; j++)       
            for (k=0; k<MATSIZE; k++){
                c[j][i] += a[j][k] * b[k][i];
                printf(".");
            }
    }

    printf("\nResult Matrix:\n");
    for (i=0; i<MATSIZE; i++){
        for (j=0; j<MATSIZE; j++) 
            printf("%d   ", c[i][j]);
        printf("\n"); 
    }
    stopTime = omp_get_wtime();
    printf("Elapsed time = %f \n", stopTime - startTime);
}
```

Comment: Why do you have a `printf` in your inner loop? *That's* eating all your runtime, not the matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

As user2357112 as already mentionned, your culprit is `printf` (and also `rand()`). These are functions that access a global state of your process and protect it (usually) by a mutex. So having such functions in a time critical parallel loop makes no sense at all, they forcibly serialize your execution.

Also you can ease your pain when you write an OMP program. You should have all those variables that you declare `private` just as local variables in the scope where they are used. Then no extra OMP annotation is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

There is a data race in your code, since `rand()` is not a thread-safe function. There is a PRNG inside that has a state and therefore cannot be invoked by multiple threads without synchronization. Use different PRNG (such as Xorshift+ of Mersenne Twister), use one generator per thread and don't forget to seed them with **different seed values** (beware of `time(NULL)`).

Comment: all correct, but most probably not the culprit for the lack of performance, which was the question, here. The loop for initialization is quadratic, where the one for the multiplication itself is cubic.

Comment: Agree, I upvoted your answer (I wrote mine concurrently :). My answer was a bit long for comment.